# why is my autocomplete not working?

Tags: forms, ajax

i'm working with groups and users, and i would like to display only the users that are not already in a group to prevent errors while writing the name of the user.

Here is the menu :

```
$items['mod/%group/membership/autocomplete/%/%'] = array(
    'page callback' => 'my_autocomplete',
    'page arguments' => array(1, 4, 5),
    'access callback' => 'group_access',
    'access arguments' => array('administer group', 1),
    'file' => 'my_file.inc',
    'type' => MENU_CALLBACK,
  );
```

Here is the form :

```
$autocomplete_path = 'mod/' . $group->gid . '/membership/autocomplete/' . $someData;
$form['content']['user'] = array(
        '#type' => 'textfield',
        '#autocomplete_path' => $autocomplete_path,
        '#required' => TRUE,
        '#element_validate' => array('my_validation'),
      );
```

And for the autocomplete function :

```
function my_autocomplete(Group $group, $is_member, $string = '') {
  $matches = array();
  if($string) {
    //do things
  }  
  drupal_json_output($matches);
}
```

And it doesn't display anything on my form. However, if i don't check the $string, i will have all the data i want but it will not be display in function of what i'm writing which makes it pretty useless.
I know there is nothing in the $string but i don't see how i will be able to populate it.

Thanks for your help :)

Comment: What is `$string` for?

Comment: it's what the user is writing in the input (i took example of /user/autocomplete)

Comment: Why do you override it with `= ''` then? You lose the value of the input :/

Comment: It isn't an override, it's a basic value in case of nothing is returned.

Comment: Then I don't understand why you said "I know there is nothing in the `$string`...". Why is it empty if the user wrote something in the field? (Sorry if I misunderstand everything)

Comment: That's what i would like to know ^^ . I know something is returned, and i know it is empty. I change the default value in the function (like $string='a') because i still get an empty var instead of the default one. However if i write $string = 'a' in the function, i will have all the users beginning by 'a' displayed.

Comment: I guess something's wrong in your relashionships between $form, hook_menu and page callback then... But I rechecked several times and I don't see what it could be :(

Comment: Try changing `$items['mod/%group/membership/autocomplete/%/%']` to `$items['mod/%group/membership/autocomplete/%']`, the `page arguments` to `array(1, 4)`, and clearing the caches

Comment: Tried and still have the exact same problem :(

Comment: Slightly talk too fast. My $autocomplete_path finishes with a '/' so i changed my $items['mod/%group/membership/autocomplete/%/%'] to $items['mod/%group/membership/autocomplete/%/'] and it's working :) Thanks for your help